# as3 caching classes, ASO files

Tags: actionscript-3, caching, gaia

I have a problem with classes in my project, when I declare new functions or variables, or just trace something in them, it doesn't work, like it doesn't upload new functionality. I found out that I should delete aso files and I did that, from controls panel. but still it doesn't work. maybe I did something wrong? maybe it's because I use Gaia Framework?

and one more thing when I rename my classes and asign this new classes to my movieclips, then it works fine

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Flash? Flex Builder? Flash Develop?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are testing I would suspect your browser is caching your swf. Try clearing your cache and see if that helps.

If it does work, consider getting a browser extension/plugin that lets you disable the cache for things like these.

Comment: I wasn't working with the Gaia framework, but I was having a similar problem and clearing the browser cache fixed it. +1